# Why is iframe content downloading as a file?

Tags: html, azure, iframe, azure-blob-storage

When visiting the webpage with the following iframe, the HTML file is downloaded as a file instead of just displaying on the page within the iframe. Why is it downloading and how can it be embedded correctly within a webpage?

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="https://example.com/files/example.htm" width="780" height="1400"></iframe>
```

If it helps to know, the file is being stored in Azure Storage as a blob:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="https://aerccgrsuatpnoapoddat01.blob.core.windows.net/pnoa/html/00460522-001.htm" width="780" height="1400"></iframe>
```

Comment: You probably have the `Content-Disposition` header set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to set the `Content-type` of the blob as `text/html`. Then in my side, I can see it works in iframe.

The steps as below:

Nav to azure portal -> your storage account -> Storage Explorer(preview) -> blob container -> your blob container -> right click the .htm file, and select properties -> Then set `Content-type` to `text/html`. -> click save button.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what the solution was. Is there a way to change the content type for all files in a container folder? They are not in the root of the container [container-name]/[folder-name]. They are uploaded using Data Factory.

Comment: What about if we're doing just HTML, and using FTP to upload files to our own server?